# getElementsByTagName('head') returns one head even if more are defined in the page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I know that a web page has an implied `<head>` tag even when there is none declared in the file. I was just curious in testing `getElementsByTagName('head')` when there is none and it does return a `<head>` tag.

However, when I placed more than one `<head>` in the page... it returns a unified head. why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the browser "corrects" your HTML to always include a single `<head>`. Otherwise your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

HTML parsers are said to be very much forgiving(I heard this feature makes them faster, not sure) about errors in parsing and evaluating HTML. Whatever you give, it will parse it without any error trying to be near to what you meant. So you are only supposed to have one head element. The browser will change it to a correct form, depending on the implementation. So when the javascript executes it will return the existing `head` element, after the correction.